# Convert Varbinary to PDF in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf

I have a SQL table with varbinary type column and I stored PDF File in it.
This is how the file looks in database:

```
0x4D007900500044004600460069006C0065002E00700064006600
```

How do I convert it so that I can see PDF file's content?

For example: In same column I stored XML file and I can see the XML file content by using `CONVERT()` function:

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(XML,(CONVERT(varbinary(max),[fileColumn]))) from table
```

Comment: varbinary is binary of variable length. Simply retrieve the column into a byte array and save it to disk as a .pdf file. SQL Server doesn't understand what a PDF is or how to render it, so you need to save it off and let your operating system and installed applications handle that. Trying to coax that in SQL is going to be terrible performance (you could do it with a CLR function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't need *converting* as such - the data is already PDF data, as you stated yourself. You just need to put it somewhere where a program which knows how to display PDF data can read and understand it.

As the above comment notes, the easiest way to achieve that is by putting it into a file. Then you can open it in Adobe Reader or other PDF program of your choice.

SQL itself (or to be precise, any SQL Server client software that I know of) cannot render PDFs to the screen directly, if that's what you're asking.

---

P.S. The key difference between that and your XML example is that XML is a text-based format (whereas PDF is binary), and also SQL Server has a built-in understanding of XML already, so it's easy for a) SQL to parse the data using its built-in functions, and b) a SQL client to display it, because it's already able to display text.